# How to concatenate all the numbers in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For clarification, I don't just only want a random letter word. I need the random numbers in my code later on also.

I made the following code which gives a random 7 letter word.
Here is the code:-

```
import random
key_num = []
for initial_num in range(7):
    key_num.append(random.randrange(1,26))
def value(n):
    return (chr(int(n) + 64))
print value(key_num[0]) + value(key_num[1]) + value(key_num[2]) + value(key_num[3]) + value(key_num[4]) + value(key_num[5]) + value(key_num[6])
```

My question is there any better way to concatenate the word using the random numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve concatenation in a single for loop. 
Try Below Code:

```
import random
key_num = []
for initial_num in range(7):
    key_num.append(random.randrange(1,26))
def value(n):
    return (chr(int(n) + 64))
final_string = ""
for i in range(7): # Range of Numbers you want
    final_string += value(key_num[i]) # Concatenate random character
print final_string
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
word = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(string_length)]
```

Is how i would make a random string

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to solve this and also improve your code. You should definitely checkout [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

If you want to stick to your original code as much as possible, how about this basic solution:

```py
import random
key_num = []
for initial_num in range(7):
    key_num.append(random.randrange(1,26))
def value(n):
    return (chr(int(n) + 64))

# so far unchanged, here comes the new bit:
print ''.join(value(k) for k in key_num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged your question Python2.7. If you can use Python3 instead, you can use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) to make things rather simple:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from random import choices

print ("".join(choices(ascii_lowercase,k=7)))
```

If you're stuck in Python2, you can implement a (simplistic) `random.choices` thus:

```
from random import choice

def choices(s,k=1):
  return [choice(s) for _ in xrange(k)]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a way:

```
from random import randrange
from string import ascii_lowercase

def random_str(length=7):
    return ''.join(ascii_lowercase[randrange(len(ascii_lowercase))] for _ in range(length))
```

`ascii_lowercase` is just `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`; i select a random entry from that and join the single letters with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

...actually [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=randint#random.choice) is better suited for that. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54961462/4954037).